# How to echo environment variable in variable in DOS

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I am not sure if this question holds true but I am trying to get solution for my problem as below:

```
set var1=ABC
set otherevars=C:\temp2
set %var1%dfts=C:\temp\test
```

all works fine till above line but, can we get the value of below

I am looking set another environment variable as below:

```
echo set projdeflts=%var1%dfts;%otherevars%
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am expecting projdeflts as C:\temp\test;C:\temp2

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way a cmd script is parsed. It is just parsed once and as a result, when it comes to this line:

```
echo set projdeflts=%var1%dfts;%otherevars%
```

%var1% is evaluated as is, thus resulting in ABCdfts. You cannot nest these lookups. But given that all the information is already in the script itself, you can simply call the result. Eg:

```
echo set projdeflts=%ABCdfts%;%otherevars%
```

If you want the control of having nested variable assignment, you will need to switch to a more powerful scripting language, such as Powershell.

Then you can simply do:

```
$var = @{"var1" = "ABC"}
$var.var1 #(which prints ABC)
```

Or just

```
$var1 = "ABC"
$var1 #(which prints ABC)
```